# Does the second order non-linear ODE $yy''=f(x)f(x)''$ have a general solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was working on [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249135/system-of-non-linear-differential-equations-alpha-1-gf-g-beta-1-f-0-and) and came across an equation of the form
\begin{align}
yy''=f(x)f(x)''.
\end{align}
The equation $yy''=f(x)$ does not have a general solution (that I or WA can find), but this equation has the particular solutions $y_{0,1}=\pm f(x)$, which gives me a bit of hope. I also tried a solution of the form $y=\sqrt{f(x)^2+g(x)}$ for some $g(x)$ to be determined, but I believe only $g(x)\equiv0$ works.

Non-linear equations don't always have general solutions or transformations to simpler equations given particular solutions, but perhaps someone is aware of one for such an equation?

**Edit**

I've channeled my inner Claude Leibovici for this idea, taking $x$ to be the dependent variable and $y$ to be the independent variable:

\begin{align}
y''=-\frac{x''}{(x')^3},\quad\text{and}\quad
f''=-\frac{x''}{(x')^3}f'+\frac{1}{(x')^2}f''.
\end{align}
So then
\begin{align}
-y\frac{x''}{(x')^3}=-\frac{x''}{(x')^3}ff'+\frac{1}{(x')^2}ff'\quad\longrightarrow\quad
x''+\frac{ff''}{y-ff'}x'=0.
\end{align}
Using the integrating factor
\begin{align}
\ln(\mathrm E)&=\int\frac{ff''\mathrm dy}{y-ff'},\\
\left(\mathrm Ex'\right)'=0&\quad\longrightarrow\quad
x'=\frac{k_1}{\mathrm E},\\
x(y)&=k_1\int\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm E}+k_2.
\end{align}

This strikes me as a solution at first, but after thinking a little I'm not so certain. Evaluating the integral for $\mathrm E$ requires knowing the first and second derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$, which I'm not sure is possible without knowing the solution to the original ODE.

Comment: Perhaps let $f(x)=x^2$ and try to find a Taylor series for $y$ with $y(0)=1$?

Comment: This DE can be written as $((y-f)(y+f))''=2(y-f)'(y+f)'$.

Comment: I don't think there is a closed form general solution.  Even for $f(x)=x^a$ ($a$ constant) we don't know of a one-parameter family of solutions to this Emden-Fowler equation ($y''=Ax^ny^m$) except for a handful of obvious cases according to *Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations* (Polyanin & Zaitsev, 2003).